# Block device file exists but "No media found" error rises on access

Tags: usb, unix, debian, usb-flash-drive

I have problem with my USB flash drive: block device file appears in /dev (/dev/sdc) but when I try launch fdick, mount or event cat on it, "No media found" error rises

```
root@nuclight:~# ls -l /dev  | g sdc
brw-rw---T 1 root floppy    8,  32 Aug  1 14:05 sdc

root@nuclight:~# fdisk /dev/sdc
fdisk: unable to open /dev/sdc: No medium found
```

Device also appears in lsusb output:

```
root@nuclight:~# lsusb 
...
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 13fe:3100 Kingston Technology Company Inc. 2/4 GB stick
```

dmesg:

```
root@nuclight:~$ dmesg | tail -n 22
[ 8309.368063] ata3.01: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 8309.376124] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/03:45:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[ 8309.376129] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/03:0c:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[ 8309.376216] ata3.00: ACPI cmd c6/00:10:00:00:00:a0 (SET MULTIPLE MODE) succeeded
[ 8309.376218] ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[ 8309.492298] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 8309.532094] PM: resume of devices complete after 6125.660 msecs
[ 8309.532265] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[ 8309.532267] Restarting tasks ... done.
[ 8310.052567] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 8311.861011] ATL1E 0000:02:00.0: eth0: NIC Link is Up <100 Mbps Full Duplex>
[ 8311.861792] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[ 8321.976010] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[ 8491.332026] usb 2-5: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[ 8491.464741] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=3100
[ 8491.464746] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 8491.464750] usb 2-5: Product: 2250 PRAM               
[ 8491.464753] usb 2-5: Manufacturer:                         
[ 8491.465160] scsi7 : usb-storage 2-5:1.0
[ 8492.464703] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access              2250 PRAM        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 8492.466460] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 8492.468735] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk

I suspect this flash drive is damaged. How can I make it work?
```

p.s. I use Debian 7 x64

Comment: please run "dmesg" to gather more information about error. By "restore it" do you mean "reformat it so it can be used again", or "recover data on it" ?

Comment: Ok, in dmesg nothing special. Post edited

Answer (score 2):

According to the updated question, it seems the USB device is detected as "sdb" and NOT "sdc" on which fdisk was attempted. If that is correct, than "sdc" is probably CD/DVD or some other device with removable media. Please note that block devices can (and do) change names across 
reboots (if you want permanence you should be using LABEL= or UUID=)

If that is typo, then please update question - first do "fdisk /dev/xxx" and copy/paste the output, and AFTER that "dmesg" and its output.